# How to interrupt IntroJS.js tutorial with a onclick on an element and then carry on?

Tags: javascript, intro.js

I am working on a tutorial for [this](http://www.mapping.cityoflondon.gov.uk/geocortex/mapping/?viewer=compass) site.

On the 3rd step, I highlight an element, which I ask the user to click, this changes one of elements, which I then want to use in the next step. However when the next step occurs, the correct element is highlighted, but the popup does not appear and the opacity of the IntroJS step is not correct.

Is there a way I can interrupt the tutorial to allow the user to click on a particular element and then once they have done that to carry on and go to the next step.

If you want to have a look at the correct tutorial, click on the **Getting Started** text on the left Home Panel, which should start the tutorial

Answer (score 0):

This occurs because intro.js is accessing the DOM to calculate the position of the popover prior to the update being completed.

(You can verify this by inspecting the page elements and finding the popover element appended to the DOM, but with a position that is invalid or offscreen.)

If this is the case, a simple $setTimeout(...) to delay the invocation of your nextStep function should do the trick e.g.

```
// update DOM element, then...
//
setTimeout( function() {
  introJs().start().nextStep();
},100};
```